# Flutter setting default font family for non-material apps

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use a default font family for my flutter app but according to the [Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts#3-set-a-font-as-the-default) for setting a default font family we should declare it as a theme data in our MaterialApp instance

> [Text](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts#3-set-a-font-as-the-default) :  To use a font as the default, set the fontFamily property as part of the app’s theme. The value provided to fontFamily must match the family name declared in the pubspec.yaml.

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Custom Fonts',
  // Set Raleway as the default app font.
  theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

But I don't want to use MaterialApp for my app and I want to set a font as the default font of my application , any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

No.
you can use your font anywhere that you want

```
Text("Helloo!",style:TextStyle(fontFamily:"font name"))
```

Comment: I know that but I want set it globally

Comment: no problem.
you can do that like code and use your custom font.